# Function has a return type of 'Future<Station>' but doesn't end with a return statement flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, asynchronous, dart

I'm trying to return a Future object from a function in `flutter`, I have to add the return statement inside the database query block, can't access it from outside, but I have this error `Function has a return type of 'Future<Station>' but doesn't end with a return statement flutter` because it is expected to find a return statement at the end of the function, here if the full example :

```dart
  Future<Station> gettingStationData(String stationName) async {
    var databasesPath = await getDatabasesPath();
    String path = join(databasesPath, 'main.db');
    Database database = await openDatabase(path, version: 1);
    database.transaction((tnx) async {
      List<Map> stationQuery = await tnx.rawQuery(
          "SELECT * FROM Station WHERE stationName = ?", [stationName]);
      Station station = Station(
          key: stationQuery[0]['key'],
          stationName: stationQuery[0]['stationName'],
          cityName: stationQuery[0]['cityName'],
          stationLatitude: stationQuery[0]['stationLatitude'],
          stationLongitude: stationQuery[0]['stationLongitude']);
      return station;
    });
  }
```

Whenever I try to add `return station;` at the end of the function it gives me `unresolved reference` error . and whenever I try to access the function it returns a `null`. any help with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return what `database.transaction(...)` is returning.

```
return database.transcation((tnx) async { ...
```